# EXTI interrupt STM32 error HardFault_Handler

Tags: c, stm32, interrupt, firmware

**Premise**
I am using a STM32G071KBU ..
I want to use a pin with hardware interrupts to analyze a fast pulse.

For my tests I connected a button that connects the pin to VCC when pressed, and configured the GPIO in Pull-Down with "GPIO mode" in "External Interrupt Mode with Falling edge trigger detection" and and kept the priority level at 0.

**TEST**
In my main I exchange the status of the led when a button event is intercepted ....

**PROBLEM**
When I press the button 1 time out of 10 there is a probability that the program goes into HardFault_Handler.

**EXTI2_3_IRQHandler :** interrupt management

```
/**
  * @brief This function handles EXTI line 2 and line 3 interrupts.
  */
void EXTI2_3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI2_3_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI2_3_IRQn 0 */
  if (LL_EXTI_IsActiveFallingFlag_0_31(LL_EXTI_LINE_2) != RESET)
  {
    LL_EXTI_ClearFallingFlag_0_31(LL_EXTI_LINE_2);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN LL_EXTI_LINE_2_FALLING */
    m_led_status++;
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI2_3_IRQn 1 */
  /* USER CODE END EXTI2_3_IRQn 1 */
}
```

**GPIO SETUP**

```
void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{    
  LL_EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStruct = {0};
  LL_GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  LL_IOP_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_IOP_GRP1_PERIPH_GPIOB);
  LL_IOP_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_IOP_GRP1_PERIPH_GPIOA);

  /**/
  LL_GPIO_ResetOutputPin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin);

  /**/
  LL_EXTI_SetEXTISource(LL_EXTI_CONFIG_PORTB, LL_EXTI_CONFIG_LINE2);

  /**/
  EXTI_InitStruct.Line_0_31 = LL_EXTI_LINE_2;
  EXTI_InitStruct.LineCommand = ENABLE;
  EXTI_InitStruct.Mode = LL_EXTI_MODE_IT;
  EXTI_InitStruct.Trigger = LL_EXTI_TRIGGER_FALLING;
  LL_EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStruct);

  /**/
  LL_GPIO_SetPinPull(BUTTON_GPIO_Port, BUTTON_Pin, LL_GPIO_PULL_DOWN);

  /**/
  LL_GPIO_SetPinMode(BUTTON_GPIO_Port, BUTTON_Pin, LL_GPIO_MODE_INPUT);

  /**/
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = LL_GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.OutputType = LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = LL_GPIO_PULL_NO;
  LL_GPIO_Init(LED1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI2_3_IRQn, 0);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI2_3_IRQn);

}
```

**main management**

```
// GENERAL MACRO
#define GPIO_PIN_SET(a,b)       (((GPIO_TypeDef*)(a))->BSRR = b)
#define GPIO_PIN_CLR(a,b)       (((GPIO_TypeDef*)(a))->BRR = b)
#define LED1_L()                GPIO_PIN_SET(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin)
#define LED1_H()                GPIO_PIN_CLR(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin)

volatile static uint8_t m_led_status;

void app_main_loop(void) {

    if (m_led_status & 0x01) {
        LED1_H();
    } else {
        LED1_L();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
  LL_APB2_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB2_GRP1_PERIPH_SYSCFG);
  LL_APB1_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB1_GRP1_PERIPH_PWR);   
  LL_SYSCFG_DisableDBATT(LL_SYSCFG_UCPD1_STROBE);
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();

  while (1)
  {
    app_main_loop();
  }
}
```

I have tried using both LL and HAL libraries !! 
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you ask this same question an hour or so ago? I remember seeing the exact same title before. If so, please don't repost the same question again, edit the question you have to improve it.

Comment: The old post was deleted by the administration, I couldn't improve it

Comment: Kinda hard to debug a hard fault by looking at the source code.  OK, Kinda hard to debug a hard fault at all :-)   Perhaps some of the suggestions here will help you? https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/cortex-m-fault-debug